# Executing each Array of Integers in a certain position of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

And an `Array` of Integers:

```
int[] x = {5, 10, 15, 20, 25};
```

I want to execute each `Array` of Integers in a certain position of the `ArrayList`. I’ve tried the following code but it's not working as expected!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    for(int i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(i);
        System.out.print(" , ");
        System.out.print(number(i));
    }
}


private static long number(int pos) { 
    int y = 0;
   return (long) pos / list.get(x[y]);
}
```

**Current Output:**

```
0 , 0
1 , 0
2 , 0
3 , 0
4 , 0
5 , 0
6 , 1
7 , 1
8 , 1
9 , 1
10 , 1
11 , 1
12 , 2
.
.
.
```

**Expected Output** (something like):

```
0 , 0
1 , 0
2 , 0
3 , 0
4 , 0
5 , 5
6 , 5
7 , 5
8 , 5
9 , 5
10 , 10
11 , 10
12 , 10
.
.
.
```

I tried different methods but couldn't manage to solve it, any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What is that you want to do?

Comment: Why do you define `y` variable inside `number` method if it's always 0 ?

Comment: @mibac This is the closest I could get.

Comment: @Uma Kanth I'm trying to implement a section header for a ```RecyclerView``` in ```Android```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer like you want to follow the pattern in your expected answer, first of all, when you say `list.get(x[y])` it gives you `list.get(5)` which is **6** as you started to count from **1** not **0** when filling the list, So you are preferred to do one of two options:

1- make your count from `0`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
.
.
}
```

2- make your get line with `x[y]-1`:

```
list.get(x[y] - 1);
```

And in both cases when you want to get the result, you must multiply it with the value of the list index which is `x[y]`:

```
private static long number(int pos) { 
    int y = 0;
   return Math.round(pos / list.get(x[y]) * x[y]);
}
```

Comment: I like the fact that the method ```number()``` in your answer is close to what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because `y` variable inside `number` method is always 0. Because of that `number` method always returns `pos / list.get(5)`. That's why 2nd number increases when number is divisible by 6. From what I noticed your expected output is number divided by 1 rounded down to nearest 5.

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest you to do is to maintain a counter variable to check if the number in the array has reached or not.

```
int []arr = {2, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30};

int size = arr[arr.length - 1];
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();

int k = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
  if(i == arr[k])
   k ++;
  if(k == 0)
    list.add(0);
  else
    list.add(arr[k - 1]);
}

for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
   System.out.println(i + ", " + list.get(i));

Output:
0, 0
1, 0
2, 2
3, 2
4, 2
5, 5
6, 5
...
```

---

```
private static long number(int pos) { 
   return list.get(pos);
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I just your the code and for some reason it gives error ```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1```.

Comment: @M-Y Yeah I'm sorry. I updated the code, try it now.